# Como fazer uma operação em um Trigger? MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TRIGGER aumentarsalario 
AFTER INSERT 
ON empregados
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMPREGADOS SET SALARIO = NEW.SALARIO * (NEW.SALARIO*(10/100)) WHERE NEW.SALARIO < 900;
END IF
END
```

Como faço para colocar mais 10% em um produto? em qual ponto estou errando.

Comment: Lembrei, por isso apaguei kkkk

Comment: @EuaeLucas se o que você precisa é alterar todos os registros que tem o salário menor que 900 uma única vez, a `trigger` não é uma saída viável. A melhor maneira seria criar uma função e executa-lá somente quando necessário. A `trigger` vai ser executada toda vez que um registro for inserido/atualizado/excluido, ou seja, todas as vezes que cadastrar um empregado, todos os empregados que tiver o salário menor que 900 receberá um aumento de 10%, inclusive o que esta sendo inserido agora.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você não precisa fazer um `UPDATE` para alterar o próprio registro.
Essa `trigger` vai ser executada toda vez que um registro novo for inserido, a variável `NEW` irá conter os dados desse novo registro, então para fazer o que você precisa basta fazer `SET NEW.coluna = valor`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER aumentarsalario 
AFTER INSERT 
ON empregados
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SET NEW.SALARIO = NEW.SALARIO * 1.1 WHERE NEW.SALARIO < 900;
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta isso!

```
CREATE TRIGGER aumentarsalario 
  AFTER INSERT 
  ON empregados FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE EMPREGADOS SET SALARIO = 1.1 * SALARIO WHERE SALARIO < 900;
END;
```

Comment: *0.1 não adiciona 10% , ele muda pra 10% do valor.
Alterei algumas coisas , tenta denovo

Comment: Aponta erro na sintaxe. Não consigo criar essa trigger de jeito nenhum.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que assim resolva seu problema:

```
create trigger AUMENTARSALARIO
after insert on EMPREGADOS
for each row
begin
  update EMPREGADOS set SALARIO = SALARIO * 1.1 where SALARIO < 900;
end;
```

Você tinha deixado um `END IF` lá que não era necessário; além disso, fazia o salário receber `ele mesmo * 10%`, quando deveria somar.